# FInding max value from TOP selection grouped by key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Apologies for goofy title.  I am not  sure how to describe the problem.

I have a table in SQL Server with this structure;

```
ID                varchar(15)    
ProdDate          datetime    
Value             double
```

For each ID there can be hundreds of rows, each with its own ProdDate.  ID and ProdDate form the unique key for the table.

What I need to do is find the maximum Value for each ID based upon the first 12 samples, ordered by ProdDate ascending.

Said another way.  For each ID I need to find the 12 earliest dates for that ID (the sampling for each ID will start at different dates) and then find the maximum Value for those 12 samples.

Any idea of how to do this without multiple queries and temporary tables?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a common table expression and `ROW_NUMBER` to logically define the `TOP 12` per `Id` then `MAX ... GROUP BY` on that.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ProdDate) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT Id,
       MAX(Value) AS Value
FROM   T
WHERE  RN <= 12
GROUP  BY Id
```

Comment: Had my question a bit off I need the ProdDate of the sample with the max value within the 12 months.  This is one level more of processing.  I will look at your solution and see what can be done to modify it further.

Comment: @user1753352 - 12 **months** or 12 **rows**?